# Set default value of sj:select

Tags: jquery, struts2

I'm using the struts2-jquery plugin I need to set a default value for the `sj:select` drop-down widget.

The widget currently works and will display all the appropriate values (from a map, where the value is the value to be displayed on the menu).  It is called from an action class that handles the appropriate methods.

```
<s:url id="menu" action="getListofObjects" />
<sj:select name="list" href="%{getListofObjects}" list="objects"/>
```

Lets say the object is blue and its ID is 3.  Currently I have a `.jsp` page where all the objects are listed.  If I click on the '3' it calls an action, which finds the object (blue) and saves both '3' and blue inside the action.  Then, it calls a new `.jsp` page which displays info about the object.

What I want is to have an `sj:select` drop-down menu that will default to the object I selected (in this case, the colour blue), but when clicked will display the rest of the objects.  When I call the widget with `value="%{object}"` I will get the same object displayed twice.

Does anyone have a solution for this?  I've seen people using jQuery to scrub the dropdown of duplicates but I want to know if there is a true solution where I can set the default based upon what the dropdown menu returns.

Also, I'm using `sj:select` because I have some double/triple select methods so I cannot switch to s:select.

Thanks.

**Update -> More Code**

**page1.jsp**

```
<s:iterator value="penList">
<tr class="detail">
<td class="detail">
<s:url action="penUpdate" var="urlTag">
<s:param name="penId"><s:property value="penId"/></s:param></s:url>
<a href="<s:property value="#urlTag" />"><s:property value="penId" /></a></td>
```

**penUpdateAction.java**

```
public String execute(){
    getPen();
    return Action.SUCCESS;
}
public PenVO getPen(){
penVO = penService.searchPens(penId);
name = penVO.getName();
    id = penVO.getPenId();
return penVO;
}
```

Page1 calls the penUpdateAction which calls page2

**Page2.jsp**

```
<s:url id="nameList" action="getNames" />
<sj:select name="name" href="%{nameList}" list="names" onChangeTopics="reloadsecondlist"/>
```

This is a dropdown menu that shows all available names.  It is working but I want it to DEFAULT to the value stored in the penUpdateAction class.  Then the user can change the value or leave it as is.

Comment: The `name` attribute should contain the value for pre-selection, at least that's how it works for the normal select tag--try it for the jQuery equivalent.

Comment: I don't seem to understand your question. Can you post your code, the Object you are setting in the `sj:select` and your action class code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this. I have not tested it but i think it should work:

```
<sj:select name="list" href="%{getListofObjects}" list="objects" listKey="id" listValue="name" value="%{id}"/>
```

**Note:** The value of `listKey` and `listValue` must be properties of the `Object` in the `list` you are populating the `sj:select` with.

The `id` property set in `value` attribute should be a property in your action class which carries the default value that you want to set. Let say the value  is `3`, and you have a select list like this

```
<select>
    <option value="1">Yellow</option>
    <option value="2">Black</option>
    <option value="3">Blue</option>
</select>
```

When the page loads, the select will display by default `Blue`.
Let me know if u have issues doing this.

Comment: Thanks :)  Needed to add onSuccessTopics to get the dependent drop-down working but your code works.